# why hooks beforeDestroy in Sequelize don't work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
      class Module extends Model {
      static init(sequelize) {
        return super.init(
          {
            //columns
          },
          {
            sequelize,
            modelName: "Module",
            paranoid: true,
            deletedAt: "destroyTime",
            hooks: {//why this hook doesnt work
              afterDestroy: (module, options) => {
                console.log("Deleting module:", module.id);
                // Perform actions before delete
                // Update related records or perform other operations
                // Call the destroy method to continue with the deletion
                return module.destroy(options);
              },
            },
          }
          );
      } 
    }
    Module.init(sequelize);
    //Sequelize sync methode
```

**i can see my record deleted but hooks doesnt work it s like it ignore it**

> Note : that a class called ELement blong to Module

Comment: I see that you're trying to destroy the instance of `Module` model that was already destroyed. What's the point in that?

Comment: @Anatoly this is just my entity not an instance i dont really understand why you told me that iwant to destroy something that already destroyed can you explain me that line of code in hooks ?

Comment: You have `module` param as the first param of the `afterDestroy` - this is an instance of the `Module` model (represents a certain record in DB) and obviously the prefix `after` in the name of the hook tells us that the instance was already deleted and you just have an opportunity to do some afterwards having the deleted instance in hand.